# Quality of image matching (Conceptual)

Tags: image-processing

How can I define (statistically)  quality of image matching (area-based, feature-based ) between two images.

'If its wrong forum to ask such conceptual questions , please guide me to other forum'.
Thanx and regards,

Comment: Background information: "area-based" and "feature-based" are probably related to this paper: [Combination of feature-based and area-based image registration technique for high resolution remote sensing image](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=4422809)

Comment: Are you tring to measure the registration error after two images have been matched (registered)? What kind of geometrical deformations (warping) do you expect in the two images?

Comment: @ rwong There are two  aplications 1-if I two geometrically stable images and I am matching them together, Then I can use cross-correlation 2. What I am confused, if in these two images some parts are not stable, can I still use cross-correlation or there are some better statistical measures.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably look at the [cross-correlation](http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/correlate/) between the images.